# Making a EXISTING CMS site compatible for mobile site NOT REDIRECT

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, content-management-system, expressionengine

Making a EXISTING CMS site compatible for mobile site NOT REDIRECT

Hi All. 
I am currently creating a mobile version of an expression engine site that we use.

I am having problems with this, because typically I can just use media quires, or use redirect scripts.

However, the layout of the mobile site will be completely different from the desktop, so I can't just fiddle with a media quires for the CSS (as site just looks to different).

I was thinking of using a javascript to wipe the code or markup (php) if the device is mobile BUT it would mean perhaps loading two versions of code anytime a page loads up (not good for mobile). Eg one code for desktop and another for mobile.

I can't change the file names eg (mobile_index) because it is a CMS and the links wont link up correctly. I have tried this a few times , and also editing the .HTACCESS file, but it simply didnt work.

So if anyone knows how do I change the code of a page if the device mobile, but cant change file name, directory or any of that :-)

Cheers

Daragh

Comment: Can you explain why you can't or won't use a redirect? Is the objection to both client and server side directs?

Answer (score 2):

Why no redirect? If I was in your position, which I was a few months ago, I would handle this totally different:

- Install Multiple Site Manager by ExpressionEngine:  http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/sites/index.html
- Add another site -- mobile
- Give it a proper domainname like m.domain.com
- Give it its own template group
- ... and redirect with http://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site/

Now you can manage both installations from the same CMS and **both installations can access existing channels, modules, extensions and members**. This will keep your code fast and clean.

Adding a bunch of conditionals will only slow down installation.

Comment: Sorry for big delay, I was not notified of a response for this.

Would I have to enter the information twice if I did this way ?. Also the side has many class files associated, and it would be quite hard to link them all together for new template name.  

So I don't really use the re-direct for that reason .

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could mess with media queries - it's the most flexible. JS is really overkill for something like this. At larger sizes, UL>LI menus could appear, and at smaller sizes they could be hidden (display:none) and swapped to select lists; divs can be replaced, elements dropped or resized. I also combine them with different snippets or embeds so you can tailor the content out as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like [MX Mobile Device Detect](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-mobile-device-detect). It gives you some variables that can detect if the user is on a mobile device that you could use in conditionals in your templates.

Comment: Hey man, thats awsome, however I am on expression Engine 1.6.2 and that update dosn't work :'( Thanks very much though

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that. How about detecting mobile browsers with PHP and adding your own mobile detection variables like in [this article on Design Karma](http://www.designkarma.co.uk/blog/comments/going-truly-adaptive-with-expressionengine)? That process might be a little different for EE1. If I recall, you added global variables in `path.php` there.

Comment: Hey, I just tried that and added it into the 'path.php' but no luck :-( ,I looked at the code, and it simply ignores what HTML I have written into the condition which was : 'code'   {if global:site_version=='full'}
       <h1>FOR DESKTOP </H1>
       {/if} 'code'